# Как сделать сортировку по полю из другой таблицы?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

Помогите пожалуйста составить SQL запрос.

Нужно вывести данные из таблицы `articles` с привяской к таблице `prices` по полю `id_price` с сортировкой по полю `sort`. Точнее приоритет сортировки сначало поле `sort`, затем поле `title`

```
prices
id price sort active
1  2400  2    1
2  1000  1    1
3  4805  3    1

articles
id title id_price active
1  test3 2        1
2  test7 3        1
3  test4 2        1
4  test5 2        1
5  test6 1        1

SELECT * FROM articles WHERE active = 1 ORDER BY title ASC
```

Comment: `.. FROM articles JOIN prices ..`

Comment: @Akina, там точнее будет `LEFT JOIN` но вот как это записать никак не пойму

Comment: Наверное, надо почитать про связывание таблиц. Ну хоть что-нибудь...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял условие задачи, то запрос примерно вот такой:

```sql
SELECT pr.*, art.*
FROM articles AS art
JOIN prices AS pr ON pr.id = art.id_price 
ORDER BY pr.sort, art.title
```